# Mathematical Structure and Objects Induced by Pairs of Disjoint Subsets

Tags: graph-theory, convex-polytopes

Let $\mathcal{S}$ be a finite, discrete and non-empty set, i.e.,

$$\begin{align} \operatorname{card}\left(\mathcal{S}\right) & =:n\in\mathbb{N}^+\\ V& :=\{v\subset\mathcal{S}\ |\ v\ne\emptyset\}\\
E &:=\{(u,v)\in V\times V\ |\ u\cap v=\emptyset\}\\ \\
 \implies \operatorname{card}(V) & = 2^n-2  \\
\operatorname{card}(E)&= \frac{\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}\left(2^{n-k}-1\right)}{2}\\ & =\frac{3^n+1}{2}-2^n\end{align} $$

> **Question:**
>
> has the structure induced by the non-empty, disjoint proper subsets of a finite set already appeared explicitly or implicitly in publications?

The reason for asking is that I encountered that structure when trying classify weighted $K_4$ graphs via addition and subtraction of edgeweights; that again in hope of finding criteria for convexity of those weighted $K_4$ that admit an isometric planar embedding.

From the idea, that equality of the weight-sums of disjoint edge-sets represents critical configurations on basis of which exhaustive classification of planar euclidean $K_4$ could be possible, I was lead to the disjoint-subset structure, which generated further ideas for investigation, which I present here as appetizers for others as well:

- Have the graphs $G(V,E)$ with $V$ and $E$ defined as above, already been encountered, studied or named?
- Can the disjoint-subset structure be meaningfully be defined for discrete or continous sets with transfinite cardinality?
- if the elements of the finite set correspond to the coordinates of a cartesian space, i.e. $\mathcal{S}=\{x^i\ |\ 1\le i\le n\ \wedge\ \left(x^1,\dots,x^n\right)\in \mathbb{R}^n\}$, then the set of hyperplanes from the mapping $\lbrace(u,v)\rbrace\mapsto \lbrace\sum_{x^i\in u}{\alpha_i x^i}-\sum_{x^j\in v}{\alpha_jx^j}=0\rbrace$ defines a partitioning $\mathcal{P}$of $\mathbb{R}^n$,  that is symmetric in the $x^i$, but the connected components of $x\in\mathbb{R}^n\quad \wedge\quad \|x\|=1\quad \wedge\quad \sum_{x^i\in u}{\alpha_i x^i}-\sum_{x^j\in v}{\alpha_jx^j}\ne 0\ \forall \left(u,v\right)\in E$ are not all of equal size, leading to the question about the sizes of those connected components

  - the intersection of $n-1$ of the hyperplanes, as defined above, with the $n-1$ unit-sphere yields a set of points, whose convex hull in turn defines a polytopes; have any of those already been encountered for certain $n>2$
  - the polytopes as defined provides yield a collection of $m$-dimensional cells, $0\le m\le n-1$; do their "center points" provide a "useful" discretization of $\mathbb{R}^n$, i.e. one on which proofs can be based?

Here is an example for the hyperplanes generated in $\mathbb{R}^3$ for the values of the variables $x,y,z$ resulting in the planes $x-y=0,\ y-z=0,\ z-x=0,\ x+y-z=0,\ y+z-x=0, z+x-y=0$:[image]
[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this appears explicitly in, for example

> Wieder, T. (2008). The number of certain k-combinations of an n-set. *Applied Mathematics E-Notes, 8*, 45-52. [**Link**](http://www.math.nthu.edu.tw/~amen/2008/070301.pdf).

Plugging in the first few values of $n$ yields [**OEIS A000392**](http://oeis.org/A000392), at which a search for the string "subset" leads to the description (emphasis added):

> Let P(A) be the power set of an n-element set A. Then a(n+1) = the number of pairs of elements {x,y} of P(A) for which x and y are disjoint and for which x is not a subset of y and y is not a subset of x. Wieder calls these "**disjoint strict 2-combinations**". - Ross La Haye, Jan 11 2008

The name of this OEIS sequence is **Stirling numbers of second kind** ([**wiki**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind)) and is denoted $S(n,3)$. I imagine that this information could yield significantly more by way of references.